# What should I use for performance sensitive data access?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, entities

So I have an application which requires very fast access to large volumes of data and we're at the stage where we're undergoing a large re-design of the database, which gives a good opertunity to re-write the data access layer if nessersary!

Currently in our data access layer we use manually created entities along with plain SQL to fill them. This is pretty fast, but this technology is really getting old, and I'm concerned we're missing out on a newer framework or data access method which could be better in terms of neatness and maintainability.

We've seen the Entity Framework, but after some research it just seems that the benefit of the ORM it gives is not enough to justify the lower performance and as some of our queries are getting complex I'm sure performance with the EF would become more of an issue.

So it is a case of sticking with our current methods of data access, or is there something a bit neater than manually creating and maintaining entities?

I guess the thing that's bugging me is just opening our data layer solution and seeing lots of entities, all of which need to be maintained *exactly* in line with the database, which sometimes can be a lot of work, but then maybe this is the price we pay for performance?

Any ideas, comments and suggestions are very appreciated! :)

Thanks,

Andy.

** Update **

Forgot to mention that we really need to be able to handle using Azure (client requirements), which currently stops us from using stored procedures. ** Update 2 ** Actually we have an interface layer for our DAL which means we can created an Azure implementation which just override data access methods from the Local implementation which aren't suitable for Azure, so I guess we could just use stored procedures for performance sensitive local databases with EF for the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an ORM layer (Entity Framework, NHibernate etc) for management of individual entities. For example, I would use the ORM / entities layers to allow users to make edits to entities. This is because thinking of your data as entities is conceptually simpler and the ORMs make it pretty easy to code this stuff without ever having to program any SQL.

For the bulk reporting side of things, I would definitely not use an ORM layer. I would probably create a separate class library specifically for standard reports, which creates SQL statements itself or calls sprocs. ORMs are not really for bulk reporting and you'll never get the same flexibility of querying through the ORM as through hand-coded SQL.

Comment: So effectively have two DAL's? One for perfomance data using plain SQL and one for the rest of the bog standard stuff using EF? Could the performance DAL re-use the Entities created by the EF I wonder?.. So both DALs return the same objects to the BLL?

Comment: Yes, I'm proposing side-by-side systems, although in my defence they're doing quite different things using tools designed for their specific purpose. I would advocate NOT using EF (and the entities) for the reporting stuff because EF would tie your hands in terms of your report writing. Sometimes the low-level stuff feels simpler because it's more direct.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that doing reporting through SQL / sprocs wouldn't return you entities (unless you did lots of tedious dataset to entity programming). But I don't think this matters for reports. (Although it might matter to you.)

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures for performance. ORMs for ease of development

Do you feel up to troubleshooting some opaque generated SQL when it runs badly...? That generates several round trips where one would do? Or insists on using wrong datatypes?

Comment: I certainly don't, which is why I'm asking for advice/experience before jumping in! :) Stored procedures are a good idea, but unfortunately we really need to have our performance sensitive queries run in the cloud as well as local databases and currently stored procedures aren't supported in Azure! :( Just updating question to reflect this requirement!

Comment: Actually, re-reading what I've just written, query performance really kinda goes out the window when you have seconds worth of delay just accessing the cloud, let along running stuff.. hmm.. I think there are some fundamentals here that need addressing! :)

Comment: 'Stored procedures for performance' - the performance gain over raw SQL is (to the best of my knowledge) apocryphal. So imho SQL vs sprocs just comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @David:  Stored procs promote plan re-use better then ORMs (eg quailifying tables with schema, query text is the same etc) so you avoid compilation overhead. However, as I said, an ORM is liable to create round trips etc. A stored proc can allow one atomic call for any action.

Comment: I'm not debating that sprocs offer better performance than ORMs, for many reasons. What I meant was that sprocs don't (according to many at least) offer better performance than hand-written SQL. But I don't want to reopen the debate!

Comment: @David: I was referring to ORM-generated SQL vs proc SQL. A stored proc *is* hand-coded SQL... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/) (previously known as ibatis). It allows you to map sql statements to domain objects. This way you keep full control over SQL being executed and get cleanly defined domain model at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, I'll have to have a closer look into it.

Comment: That feature is built in to the EF, as well, in a couple different ways.

Comment: Isn't this product just an ORM where you write the SQL yourself? Aren't the benefits/drawbacks of ORMs part of the OP's question, in the form of the Entity Framework?

Comment: You can look at it as an ORM where you write SQL yourself. But it's a slippery slope once you start applying that kind of thinking. After all isn't manual mapping of SQL results just an ORM where you write SQL and map data yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Don't rule out plain old ADO.NET. It may not be as hip as EF4, but it just works.

With ADO.NET you know what your SQL queries are going to look like because you get 100% control over them. ADO.NET forces developers to think about SQL instead of falling back on the ORM to do the magic.

If performance is high on your list, I'd be reluctant to take a dependency on any ORM especially EF which is new on the scene and highly complex. ORM's speed up development (a little) but are going to make your SQL query performance hard to predict, and in most cases slower than hand rolled SQL/Stored Procs.

You can also unit test SQL/Stored Procs independently of the application and therefore isolate performance issues as either DB/query related or application related.

I guess you are using ADO.NET in your DAL already, so I'd suggest investing the time and effort in refactoring it rather than throwing it out.